# Google ocr api for android(Image to text conversion)

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I tried doing this by tesseract but the apk file generated is of 8 mb.
I have seen Goggles app in Play and its quite efficient.
I wonder how to integrate that technique.I haven't seen in any tutorial for that.
If any one knows how to do that,please respond.

Also How can I improve the quality of Tesseract which I am using.
The conversion is smooth but I wonder that If I divide the images in several parts and then separately parse,Will that be useful.

The requirement is that it should read the bills or receipts,so I want to improve the quality of text conversion.
Please suggest.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: Hello! Can you please tell me how to build tess-two. Eclipse give me error unable to compile.

Comment: Well, I followed this tutorial  http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/     Worked for me,should work for you also.

Comment: Yah I like google goggles accuracy.. how do we achieve that

Answer (score 2):

I believe you compiling this project: [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two%20Tess-Two). Am I correct?

If so, you can greatly reduce the size of the APK by compiling different APKs for specific CPU architectures. Also, you can remove most of Leptonica's functions, since you don't need them.

For better accuracy:

- if you are using the phone's camera as input, you should change the binarization algorithm. Leptonica has some binarization algorithms, try Sauvola.
- tweak tesseract's parameters for better performance vs speed.
- make sure you have a consistent resolution on all phones. Somewhere around 300dpi.

If you want a small application that runs fast on most phones, consider running the OCR on an server, not on the phone.

Tesseract is, as far as I know, by far the best OCR engine that can be compiled for Android. It has to be tweaked correctly and fed a good image.

Comment: Yes I am compiling tess-two,See the problem is,It doesn't give accurate result with different orientation ,there are problems with images taken by flash,also the result is different with different devices.i am comparing my app with Google Goggles and everytime I am failing,Ijust wanted to achieve the accuracy and speed like Goggles.What technique is google using,is it ocr through Google Drive.I have implemented Abby also,but that is also taking a lot of time infact 20 times more time than what Goggle takes.Do you have any idea to implement the same as Google Goggles.

Comment: have you so far found a solution?